# PCA doesn't reduce the dimensionality of my data

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, heatmap, pca

I would like to apply PCA on heatmaps of 18 dimensions.

```
dim(heatmaps)=(224,224,18)
```

Since PCA takes only data of  dim <= 2. I reshape my heatmaps as follow :

```
heatmaps=heatmaps.reshape(-1,18)
heatmaps.shape
(50176, 18)
```

Now, l would to apply PCA and take the first components that preserve 95% of variance.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=18)
reduced_heatmaps=pca.transform(heatmaps)
```

However the dimension of `reduced_heatmaps` remains the same as the original `heatmaps` (50176, 18).

My question is as follow : 
How to reduce the dimensionality of my heatmaps while preserving 95% of variance ?

**Strange thing**

```
pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum()
array([ 0.05744624,  0.11482341,  0.17167621,  0.22837643,  0.284996  ,
        0.34127299,  0.39716828,  0.45296374,  0.50849681,  0.56382308,
        0.61910508,  0.67425335,  0.72897448,  0.78361028,  0.83813329,
        0.89247688,  0.94636864,  1.        ])
```

It means, I need to keep 17 components to reduce the dimensionality of my data such that  l have 18 dimensions.

What is wrong ?

**EDIT : following the suggestions of  Eric Yang**

```
heatmaps=heatmaps.reshape(18,-1)
heatmaps.shape
(18,50176)
```

Then applying PCA as follow :

```
pca = PCA(n_components=11)
reduced_heatmaps=pca.fit_transform(heatmaps)
pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum()
results the following : 
array([ 0.21121199,  0.33070526,  0.44827572,  0.55748779,  0.64454442,
        0.72588593,  0.7933346 ,  0.85083687,  0.89990991,  0.9306283 ,
        0.9596194 ], dtype=float32)
```

11 components is needed to explain 95% variance of my data.

```
reduced_heatmaps.shape
(18, 11)
```

Hence we go from (18,50176) to (18, 11)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to reduce your variance is a function of your data. If you have an N dimensional gaussian with each dimension N(0,1), each dimension will explain 1/N of your variance, and so your ability to reduce dimensions via PCA would be minimal. So the results of PCA does not seem to be incorrect.

Now based on a superficial understanding of your problem, you have 18 images that are 224x224 correct? If that is correct, then your dimensionality is 224x224 not 18. So you'd want to ask what is the minimum number of pixels in my image that explain the difference between my 18 images.  (However, I could be wrong if that is not the assumption, and what you have is 18 channels for 1 image)

There is one other possibility in which you have a series of similar images (and so your dimensionality is going to be 18), and you're looking for the Eigen image. If the images are too different, you will have a minimal reduction in the dimensionality.

Comment: Hi @Eric, definitly l'm looking for the minimum number of pîxels in my image that explains the difference between 18 images. So from (224,224,18) and want to get (X, Y,18) such that X <<< 224 and Y <<< 224. (Yes 18 images of 224*224 each)

Comment: Transpose your data and rerun your PCA and see if 95% of your variance can be explained by fewer than 50176 dimensions. You want 18 rows and 50716 columns

Comment: Please see my update and let me know if it's correct

Comment: If you're looking for the # of pixels that explain the variance, than that looks correct

Comment: My purpose is to reduce the dimension of my input from (224 * 224,18) to  (Z,18) such that Z <<<< 224*224